# Chosen' Select's first option doesn't fire 'change' event

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Chosen' Select](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="field_options" name="options">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

```
$('#field_options').change(function() {
  console.log('Option changed');
});
```

If I select the second or third option, the event 'change' is fired. But it doesn't happen whit the first option.

Comment: Does it get fired when you go from Option 2 -> Option 1?  Going from Option 1 -> Option 1 there is no change

Comment: As "Option 1" the default option, it's already selected hence no `change` event is triggered. Consider adding a blank option first. Otherwise use `$("#field_options option").mouseup()` event.

Comment: To add to what @Twisty stated - if you want this event to fire on load, then fire it on load:  `$("#field_options).change(...).trigger("change");`

Comment: @danronmoon No, it doesn't :(

Comment: @Twisty the blank option solution worked perfectly. You should answer so I can mark it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider changing your HTML. See the following.

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="field_options" name="options">
  <option></option>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Now the User must change to one of the other Options which will invoke a `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start your dropdown with a blank element or something like "Choose your option", you should be able to do something like this, at least this works for regular select dropdown menus.

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="field_options" name="options">
  <option hidden>Option 1</option>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

The first option will be selected by default, but also hidden. So if you select Option 1 in the dropdown menu, it will now trigger a change event, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insist on starting with a default value, this should work for you.  Set the selected index of the select element to -1 using ordinary javascript to start off with.  Then when the user picks a selection, it is a change and your function is called.

`document.getElementById("field_options").selectedIndex=-1;`